# How to make an infinite Thread instances loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, java-threads

I would like to create threads to manipulate them (run, wait, stop). I know how to do it making an instance one by one

Class that implements runnable

```
public class ThreadRunner implements Runnable{ .....
```

Class where I create the objects

```
ThreadRunner thread1 = new ThreadRunner ("thread1");
ThreadRunner thread2 = new ThreadRunner ("thread2"); 
.
.
.
thread1.start()
.
.
```

I would like to have a loop that only ends when the user wants to (maybe with a boolean Flag). How can I create the loop that instances a Thread dynamically every 10 seconds?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a `Timer` rather than a loop.

Comment: I think I can use Thread.sleep(1000); for that, but I want to know how to creat threats dynamically

Comment: Use an array (or `Collection`) of `Thread`?

Comment: Creating a `Thread` is creating a `Thread`.  The fact that you don't know how many there are ahead of time doesn't change how you create them.  It just means that you can't declare a single variable for each one to be assigned to.  How do you usually store an indeterminate number of objects?

Comment: yes you're right, speaking about an object, I need to have a panel with threads appearing every ten seconds, and I can stop or pausing them as I want, but I need that in execution it continue appearing all the time, I was thinking about vectors or lists, or do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean stop = false;
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
while (!stop) {
    Thread t = new ThreadRunner("Thread " + threads.size());
    t.start();
    threads.add(t);
    // Do something here to check whether 'stop' should be updated.
    // And wait for 10 seconds here
}
```